Identify this Asian movie featuring a very bizarre creature
A couple days ago, I watched a soundless clip of a movie. It's asian movie. It's probably from 2005 - 2010 and in color. The movie genre probably horror/thriller. It is featuring a very bizarre creature.
The creature:
It is a very big centipede. It has a circular mouth with many sharp teeth.  I do not know if it's a ghost or a mutant, but it has a scary human hand and  face in its back.
The Actor:
I think there are 4 people. 3 guys and 1 girl. One guy is white-haired. Another guy wear a glasses. The other guy is wearing black jacket. He is the main protagonist with typical hero style I think. The girl is short haired. 
The plot:
In the clip I watch, this group is chased by the creature in an abandoned mine and some kind of facility. There's a creepy scene too in a circular stair where the creature is climb the stair chasing the group. After some chasing, the group use a mine trolley and able to get out from the mine.
update:

I believe all the actor are asian. I think it's japanese. The creature human face is really look like a noh mask 


If you watched this clip back in November, can you say whether you watched it on a computer or on TV? If it was on a computer can you try to find it by searching through your browser history, if not, do you remember the words you typed? Why was it silent? Was it a gif? How do you know it was filmed between 2005 and 2010?

@Mari-LouA It's not a gif . It's from random post on my local social network forum. Judging by it's graphic, quality and the actor clothing/gadget. It's probably from 2005++

Why don't you post the link? Let users "see" the images, don't you think it would help jog their memories?

For what it's worth, the silent clip might have been taken from a music video, or a TV series.

@Mari-LouA it's not an image (at least it has play button). It's a random post from the forum. I didn't have the link or bookmark it.

Forum? What forum?

@Vahn it would really help if you told us the name of the forum.

@AravindSuresh https://www.kaskus.co.id/




this might be the one that you are looking for :)

While this might be the correct answer, we can't rely on this video always being available, let alone available in different countries.  Adding a description as to how this movie lines up with the question would make this answer a lot better.

Yes. This is the one. I hope you write a better answer though. Thank you

I think it will be The Host (2006). Its korean movie. Aout trolley scene, i forgot if there is any scene like that. 




it's not the one. The creature from the movie clip I watched is literally have human face and hands but it's body is like  a centipede

I see.. Sorry.. I think japan movie

There is non-Asian movie from 2004 about 3 guys and a girl in a mine/cave with giant centipede. It's called Centipede!. Here's the trailer:



P.S. Also, centipede with a human face exist in Naked Lunch. Not Asian too. :(

I believe all the actor are asian. I think it's japanese. The creature human face is really look like a noh mask

The Human Centipede (2009) sounds like it. However, it's not Asian but has one Asian actor in it. The creature mentioned is not really a centipede, but three humans conjoined together. Does this trailer ring a bell?



